# Lumia 920 camera resolution

Tags: lumia, nokia-lumia-920, camera

According to [tech scecs](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile/phone/lumia920/specifications/#camera), Nokia Lumia 920 have 8.7 MP main camera. Wheh I bought it, photos resolution was 3264×2448 px (7,990,272 px). 
But after some time I noticed that maximum photos resolution is 3552×2000 px (7,104,000 px), both in *Camera* and in *Lumia Camera* applications, and I can't found way to adjst camera resolution in phone settings.

What's happening with my phone? Is Microsoft did some changes in software or something else?

Nokia Lumia 920, OS ver. 8.10.14234.375

Comment: Just I decide to learn more about image resolutions, and go to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Pixel&oldid=682769697) Wikipedia article. 
Look at [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f7/Sensoraufl%C3%B6sungen.svg/1024px-Sensoraufl%C3%B6sungen.svg.png) picture in article, I find out that image resolution depends of aspect ratio, so that 3264×2448 px is resolution for 4:3 and 3552×2000 px is for 16:9.
Accordingly, change aspect ratio in Photos+Camera settings to 4:3 give me higher resolution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lumia phones (at least high-end ones like the 920) have a sensor that supports multiple aspect ratios. The full resolution of the sensor on the Lumia 920 is 3552x2448, which works out to just about 8.7 megapixels, but that full resolution is never used.

When you set the camera app to take pictures in 4:3 aspect ratio, the full **height** of the sensor is used, for an image resolution of 3264x2448 (8 MP). With a 16:9 aspect ratio, however, the full **width** of the sensor is used, for an image resolution of 3552x1998 (7.1 MP).

The following image from the Lumia 920 imaging whitepaper illustrates this well:

[image]

This sort of sensor design dates back at least as far as the 2011 Nokia N9. The reason for it is to minimise the loss of resolution when switching between aspect ratios. With the 920, when you switch from 4:3 to 16:9, you lose about 11% resolution. Compare this to traditional 4:3 sensors where 16:9 is achieved by simply cropping the image, resulting in a 25% loss of resolution

To address the practical aspect of the question - to change the resolution back to what it was, simply change the aspect ratio. Both the Camera and Lumia Camera apps let you choose between 4:3 and 16:9. There is no other way to set the image resolution on the Lumia 920 (unlike the higher-end models with oversampling, like 1020 and 930).